# Message console on JFrame does not work by double click on jar

Tags: java, linux, swing

So I created a message console. And used append to display messages and it works perfectly by running `java -jar` JavaProgram, however when I double click on it the application runs and I see the JFrame but nothing is displayed. The text that I did append is not present.

By the way, double clicking it on windows does display the message output but on my linux system nothing is displayed.

I'm running the same version of java on each machine.

Code Below:

```
  package pdfCounter;

import java.io.*;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class App {
    public static JTextArea textComponent;
    public static int count;

    public static void main(String args[])  {

       try {


           JFrame somePanel = new JFrame();
           somePanel.add(new JLabel(" Message Console"), BorderLayout.NORTH);


           textComponent = new JTextArea(5, 10);
           somePanel.setVisible(true);
           somePanel.setSize(900, 300);
           somePanel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

           somePanel.add(new JScrollPane(textComponent));
           pdfCounter.MessageConsole mc = new pdfCounter.MessageConsole(textComponent);
           mc.redirectOut(null, System.out);
           mc.redirectErr(Color.RED, null);


           Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
           String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
           File root = new File(s);
           count = 0;
           boolean recursive = true;

           Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, null, recursive);

           for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
               try {
                   File file = (File) iterator.next();
                   if (file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                       String absoluteFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
                       append(absoluteFile);
                       PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                       count = doc.getNumberOfPages() + count;
                       doc.close();
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   continue;
               }


           }
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
            try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("NumberOfPages.txt"))) {
                    out.print(count);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
    public static void append(String absolutePath) {
        textComponent.append(absolutePath + "\n");

    }
}
```

when it gets to the `append(absoluteFile); part thats where the problem lies as it only appends on windows not linux.

UPDATE: I figured that opening it from a different file manager with double click, makes it work. With Nautilus is does not open, even when i choose to run it with java 8 or 9. Opening it with thunar(Different file manager) makes it work no problem with double clicking it. Both are set to run with java 9. I think it has something to do with folder permissions because if i run nautilus as root user, it works when double clicking.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE].

Comment: +1 to @MasterBlaster
There could be one or more of the following issues:
1) Java might not be the default program to open Jar files on your Linux machine.
2) You might have had an old version of java on your machine which is used when you double click the jar file and it might be throwing some error.
3) You might be passing some parameters (using cmd) possibly a space which the jar file is expecting, which you aren't passing while clicking the jar file.

It would be useful if you provide any code and explanation as to how your generated the Jar file.

Comment: added code sample.

Comment: Are you sure that the directory is based on the location of the jar file that you are clicking on? I'm guessing that the directory that you are expecting to be running in is not the directory you are actually running in.  You may want to output the value of currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString() and confirm that is the expected starting directory. You might also want to output any non ".pdf" files to have some additional information...?

Comment: 1) You should move this line: `somePanel.setVisible(true);` after you've added all your components to the panel, not before. 2) Are your files inside the JAR? Or are they outside?

Comment: Can you show us the manifest file? In which jars do org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils and org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument reside? Are they added to the Class-Path: attribute in the manifest file?

Comment: Hey guys please read the update i made on the post, It opens on thunar but not on nautilus/gnome files. Is this a bug on the file manager?